# Elasticsearch node is created automatically

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I work with a single elasticsearch node in development.

When I do about 10 000 `PUT` requests (about 64MB data) in a short time period another node is created automatically.

Why does this happen?

After this happens the cluster is in yellow state till I don't shut down this node manually.

I'm using logstash to put the data into elasticsearch.

Comment: another node? or shard? or index? A node is running jvm so that shouldnt just be happening on its own.

Comment: @mconlin, I don't understand Your comment.

Comment: Right now I'm using `elasticsearch-0.90.5`. The [logstash documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.2/outputs/elasticsearch) says that the elasticsearch output should be used with `elasticsearch-0.90.3`. I changed my output to `elasticsearch_http`. Right now I'm getting better results although my instance turnes into the red state.

Comment: You states another node is created automatically? I think you mean another index? Also, those versions numbers can matter a lot so be careful. What is your question exactly?

Comment: It was an additional node. Not additional index. My question was: why this node was created automatically? But since the issue has to do with logstash and the use of elasticsearch output with the wrong elasticsearch version it's not relevant anymore.

Comment: Right now I'm getting better results although my instance turnes into the red state -> I got into red state because of elasticsearch configuration: file descriptors, replicas number, ...